# How can I print every nth line from multiple file and write it as each set of that nth line?

Tags: linux, macos, awk, sed

I want to print every 108th line from five file named as chain*.dat (chaina, chain, chainc, chaind and chaine.

I have tried this command.

```
awk 'FNR%108==1 {print FILENAME,$0}' chain*.dat > frame1.pdb
```

After I tried this, It did not print the 108th line from different files as a set separately from 216th,324th... line. However, it prints the 108th,216th,324th,... of each file as a set and continued with another file.

```
chaina.dat #Frame                             
chaina.dat      108 -18.2676  -4.1726  12.7671
chaina.dat      216 -18.1870  -4.1540  12.7068
chaina.dat      324 -18.8576  -3.7915  13.0166
chaina.dat      432 -18.8460  -3.9601  12.2811
chaina.dat      540 -19.6739  -3.5707  11.5205
chaina.dat      648 -19.6330  -2.2099  11.5793
chaina.dat      756 -18.9687  -1.8901  13.0677
chaina.dat      ... ........  .......  .......
chainb.dat #Frame                             
chainb.dat      108  -8.0205 -20.6024  -6.0144
chainb.dat      216  -7.9829 -20.5061  -5.9884
chainb.dat      324  -8.5538 -20.9686  -6.0676
chainb.dat      432  -9.5947 -20.4246  -7.1129
chainb.dat      540  -9.2219 -20.5374  -8.1963
chainb.dat      648  -9.6236 -20.2414  -6.8494
chainb.dat      756  -8.9011 -20.3855  -5.0769
chainb.dat      ... ........  .......  .......
```

what I want is printing like this

```
chaina.dat      108 -18.2676  -4.1726  12.7671
chainb.dat      108  -8.0205 -20.6024  -6.0144
chaina.dat      216 -18.1870  -4.1540  12.7068
chainb.dat      216  -7.9829 -20.5061  -5.9884
```

Thank you for your help. I'm quite new to this. 
If you have manual to suggest me to read, please tell.

Comment: You were close, you could have piped output of `awk` to a `sort` command as shown in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR%108==0{print FILENAME,FNR,$0}' chain*.dat | sort -ns -k2
```

Comment: you may need to add `-s` to sort since file names may shuffle if the stable sort is not enabled by default.

Comment: @karakfa, cool I edited it to `-ns` now, let me know if any more improvements please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry for late vote and accepting this answer. I’m quite new to this community. Many thanks.

Comment: @PhakawatChusuth, not an issue, glad that it helped you, keep posting and keep learning. cheers.